# An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.IOException'.The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: c#, file, csv, io

I am trying to write a program to read records from a csv file, process them and write the results to a new file. To do so I constructed a class called CsvWriter that handles writing of headers and appending rows as I read through the main csv file. Initially I was working on it on my mac and I did not get any error whatsoever when using this class but when I switched to windows (to make a windows form application), I kept getting

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\user\Documents\correct-list.csv' because it is being used by another process.

The error I'm having is in the CsvWriter class in the following line:

```
File.WriteAllText(filename, builder.ToString());
```

I thought using System.IO.File.WriteAllText would flush and close the file automatically. I cannot find any other source of the error.
Any help to resolve this error is appreciated.

This is my code:

```
public class CsvWriter : StreamWriter
{
    private string filename;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="T:USPSAddressVerification.CsvWriter"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="filename">Filename of the csv file to write on.</param>
    public CsvWriter(string filename) : base(filename)
    {
        this.filename = filename;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Writes the header in the csv file.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="headers">Array of Headers.</param>
    /// <param name="addHeaders">Add additional headers to the csv file.</param>
    public void WriteHeader(List<string> headers)
    {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < headers.Count; i++)
        {
            if (i < headers.Count - 1) builder.Append("\"" + headers[i] + "\",");
            else builder.Append("\"" + headers[i] + "\"\n");
        }
        File.WriteAllText(filename, builder.ToString());
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Appends the row to the csv file.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="row">Row to be appended.</param>
    public void AppendRow(List<string> row)
    {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < row.Count; i++)
        {
            if (i < row.Count - 1) builder.Append("\"" + row[i] + "\",");
            else builder.Append("\"" + row[i] + "\"\n");
        }
        File.AppendAllText(filename, builder.ToString());
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried cleaning the solution? Seems to me an issue with your directory, from moving the project. Have you ensured all your dll have the correct path?

Comment: @InBetween no not that I'm aware of. I have my main program class with a function that reads from a csv and calls the WriteHeader once in the beginning to create the output file and AppendRow everytime a row needs to be added to the result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are deriving StreamWriter, this opens the file.
Instead of using File.WriteAllText you should use the StreamWriter (base) methods to write your contents.
Or don't derive StreamWriter.

Comment: omg thank you so much. I removed the StreamWriter reference and it worked like a charm. Any reason why the code worked on my mac project and not on my windows machine?

Comment: First of all, different implementations of the .net and .net core frameworks.
Then, different OS handle files differently, so it's hard to say why was it working on MAC.
For Windows - the StreamWriter instance holds a FileStream with FileShare.Read internally, so any other write would fail.
https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/streamwriter.cs,80ef9c4284b87f77

Answer (score 1):

Your class inherits from the System.IO.StreamWriter. When you are calling your constructor with the filename parameter you are calling the StreamWriter constructor wih this(filename) as well. With that command you create an instance of the StreamWriter class that access the file as long you do not dispose or close it. That is the reason why your File.WriteAllText command will fail every time. Is there any reason why your class inherits from the StreamWriter? File.WriteAllText works without it.

**Update 1**

Ups my answer was a little bit to late.

Comment: Yeah I realized that too late and looking back I find that very silly. I had been using StreamWriter before I switched to System.IO.File and did not think about removing the inheritance since it worked fine when I wrote the code and tested it on my Mac